# AngularJS $state on locationChangeSuccess

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to retrieve a custom property (breadcrumb) that I have set on the state object on the locationChangeSuccess event.  I can see the property in the console through

> event.targetScope.$state

but when I try to reference

> event.targetScope.$state.current

the values disappear

app.js

```
$stateProvider
    .state('/', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: './app/components/home/main.html',
            permission: 'home',
            breadcrumb: 'Home'
    })

    $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeSuccess", function(event, next, current) { 
        console.log(event.targetScope.$state.current);
    });
```

Can someone help on how to get the state object when this event fires?

Comment: what about something like `$transitions.onSuccess({}, function(transition) {  var property = transition.to().breadcrumb; ...`

Comment: Excellent, thanks :)